# Am I missing something, or is there a use to the TCL command?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was just looking through the console commands on the Skyrim wiki till I saw the TCL command.

The wiki states that it:

> Toggle Collision. Using the TCL command with a target toggles clipping for the target. If used while falling off a cliff, may cause a crash. Useful for unsticking your character or finding items or bodies that have fallen through a wall or floor.

I, however, don't find a use for this command. Am I missing something?

Can someone list a scenario in which you would need to use this command?

Comment: You awnsered your own question tho... look at it this way, skyrim is rather buggy at times... now your walking across the road, and run into a ditch where there is a rock and you kinda slip between the rock and the ditch. You try moving but it doesn't work, you try jumping that doesn't work either. So basicly you are stuck... now you can reload the save to unstuck yourself... or you can use the command to get past the rock and go back to killing stuff you find on your way.

Comment: Whether or not you find a command useful or not is largely irrelevant to its addition to the game - this is very much a 'why did the developer do this' question, although to answer it - you would use the command to toggle clipping, useful for unsticking your character or finding items or bodies that have fallen through a wall or floor.

Comment: No-clipping commands are not at all unique to Skyrim. Most - if not all - games which have a cheating or debug console (and many "cheating" consoles are *actually* just abused debug consoles) have this feature. Perhaps this question should be edited so that it is generalized and therefore more findable and useful to others?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you've stated from the Skyrim wiki, the purpose of the `tcl` command is to toggle no clipping mode, allowing you to essentially walk through walls. As you've quoted in your question, the Skyrim wiki states:

> Toggle Collision. Using the TCL command with a target toggles clipping for the target. If used while falling off a cliff, may cause a crash. Useful for unsticking your character or finding items or bodies that have fallen through a wall or floor.

Functionality like this is nearly always used during the original development of the game to check how things are rendered in the game world, to observe models from a variety of angles without being restricted by the movement that the game engine allows by default. It could also be used in this manner during the development of modifications for the game, and finally, it could be used by the player to run around the game world for fun when bored. There are other uses, but these are already detailed in the excerpt from the Skyrim wiki above.

Wikipedia has [the following to say](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noclip_mode#Uses_of_noclipping) about the uses of no clipping;

> Noclipping can be used to cheat, avoid bugs (and help developers debug), find easter eggs, and view areas beyond a map's physical boundary.

Comment: people largely forget the fact that the console isn't there for you. it's there for the poor QA guy that has to beat every quest in the game twice a week for 4 months.